# Force/3D Touch related crash in iOS 9 GM

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I'm seeing this crash in a client app in the GM that wasn't present in the previous beta.  It seems to be related to gesture recognizers being deallocated possibly prematurely.  It's especially prevalent on screens that use UIWebViews but definitely not isolated to them.  I can replicate it with something as simple as tapping on a text field on a screen without ever seeing a web view.  I've tried pairing down the app to it's simplest form and still get the error.  I've also tried unsuccessfully to recreate the error in a fresh app too.  This is happening to the production version of the app compiled against Xcode 6.2 and the GM of Xcode 7.  The devices are all running iOS 9.  8.x and 7.x devices are not affected.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
2015-09-10 13:42:10.246 *******[16485:728615] *** Terminating app due     to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An     instance 0x7f88f4ce7ac0 of class _UITouchForceObservable was deallocated     while key value observers were still registered with it. Current     observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f88f4ceca00> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f88f4ce7b80: Observer: 0x7f88f4ce7930, Key path: hash, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7f88f2721750>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f88f4cec830: Observer: 0x7f88f4ce7930, Key path: superclass, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7f88f2529ac0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f88f4cec910: Observer: 0x7f88f4ce7930, Key path: description, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7f88f25327a0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f88f4cec9a0: Observer: 0x7f88f4ce7930, Key path: debugDescription, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7f88f2522ee0>
```